# C# - save data to .txt file, edit and delete

Tags: c#, edit

I use terminal to add information that is saved to csv file

```
        string path = @"Savedata.csv";
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, true))
        {
            List<Diary> parts = new List<Diary>();

            parts.Add(new Diary
            {
                Date = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()),
                Time = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()),
                Name = Console.ReadLine(),
                Description = Console.ReadLine(),
                Number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())
            });

           //public struct Diary
```

I have got all the required information saved to my csv file. 
How do I edit or delete it from the csv file it is saved on, using terminal?

So for example I saved this data:

Date - 12.03,
Time - 12,
Name - John,
Description - Went to bed,
Number - 3,

I now want to edit it so it looks like this:

Date - 12.03,
Time - 11,
Name - John,
Description - Went to bed,
Number - 5,

Comment: You might create a function for finding the line, it should have some indicator like row index of the lines. Then replace the text by new text within `\n` scope.

Answer (score 0):

A CSV file doesn't really lend itself to updates in the way you want. A database would be better for your purpose. However it looks like there are 3rd party libraries which will help you do what you want to do.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library

If you don't want to use a 3rd party library then I think you will have to recreate the CSV file in order to update that one line.